# Ruby on rails Class being mistaken as a Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all, I'm experimenting with Ruby on Rails for the first time.
I'm doing a simple exercise of designing a form to receive events information and save those events in Google Calendar.
To save the events on Google Calendar I'm using the following gem: http://googlecalendar.rubyforge.org/

I have the following code for the view.

```
<h1>Welcome to Ruby On Rails Calendar</h1>

<h3>Add Event</h3>
<form action="/google_calendar/create" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Title</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Begin Date</td><td><input type="date" name="begindate" id="bagindate" /><input type="time" name="beginhour"  id="beginhour" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>End Date</td><td><input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate" /><input type="time" name="endhour" id="endhour" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Local</td><td><input type="text" name="local" id="local" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Description</td><td><input type="textarea" rows="10" name="description" id="description" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="Submit" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<%= @result_message %>
```

And for the controller I have this code (mostly taken from the gem site I shared previously).

```
class GoogleCalendarController < ApplicationController

  def create
    send_event(params[:title],params[:begindate] + " " + params[:beginhour], params[:enddate] + " " + params[:endhour], params[:local], params[:description])

    @result_message = 'Event sent successfully'
    render :welcome => index
  end

  private def send_event(title, begin_datetime, end_datetime, local, description)
    require 'googlecalendar'

    google_calendar_service = GData.new
    google_calendar_service.login(Rails.configuration.google_calendar_email, Rails.configuration.google_calendar_password)
    event = { :title     => title,
              :content   => description,
              :where     => local,
              :startTime => begin_datetime,
              :endTime   => end_datetime}
    google_calendar_service.new_event(event)
  end
end
```

The thing is that when I try to save an event I get the following error.

```
uninitialized constant GoogleCalendarController::GData
```

Supposedly  GData is a class defined in the googlecalendar gem, but seems to not being recognized as such.

I have `gem 'googlecalendar'` on my Gemfile, did `bundle install` and it appears when I do `bundle show googlecalendar`.

Does anyone know what can be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps you need require 'googlecalendar' at the top of your controller class?

Comment: try `::GData.new`, if it's defined in root namespace

Comment: Try putting `require 'googlecalendar'` at the top just below the class definition

Comment: Actually I've already tried the require 'googlecalendar' right at the top of the controller and right after the class definition but it didn't work.
With ::GData.new it also doesn't work, is there a way I can check the class namespace?

Comment: @Andre: There is no such thing as a "class namespace". Classes are objects just like any other object. They can be returned from methods. They can be passed as arguments to methods. They can be assigned to variables. Normally, they are assigned to constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is little bit wrong

try this

```
require 'googlecalendar'
google_calendar_service = Googlecalendar::GData.new
```

Since you didnot specify the namespace so first Ruby searched it in the `::`global namespace and didnot find, so expected it to be `GoogleCalendarController::GData`

---

## References

Code from the gem's `lib/googlecalendar.rb`, you can see the namespace is `Googlecalendar`

```
$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__)) unless
  $:.include?(File.dirname(__FILE__)) || $:.include?(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))

module Googlecalendar
  # List of lib files to include
  FILES = %w{calendar.rb dsl.rb event.rb gcalendar.rb gdata.rb ical.rb net.rb version.rb}
end

# Add all FILES as require
Googlecalendar::FILES.each { |f| require "googlecalendar/#{f}"}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Previously I actually tried GoogleCalendar::GData.new (with uppercase 'C') but it didn't work. Now I'm getting an error related to SSL, but at least this one is solved.

This is the new error.
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

I'm thinking of ditching this gem and try a better alternative.

Comment: Yes I am with you; try finding more simpler solutions like https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found that one yet.